# Is there a way to define a SQL trigger-like mechanism in EF4?

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers, entity-framework-4

I need to create an audit log like feature where most of one table's fields are copied to another when they are modified.  Normally, I would create a SQL trigger to do this.

Is there an Entity Framework 4 equivalent, where upon modifying Entity X I could modify Entity Y?

Comment: this sounds like a database concern anyway, why not put it there? it shouldn't be EF's job to replicate data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some approaches out there on using [ObjectContext.SaveChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/cc716714%28v=vs.100%29) and the [ObjectStateManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager?view=netframework-4.8) to perform such auditing requirements in EF

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/simonince/auditing-data-changes-in-the-entity-framework-part-1)

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/simonince/auditing-data-changes-in-the-entity-framework-part-2)